# How do i move a folder to the root of my Android Device?

Tags: root-access, apk

I'm trying to install a GPS apk (igo primo), I have the apk and all the files i need but i cant access the root folder the instructions specify.
The instructions say this :
"Move this folder to the root of your Android Device and install the iGO app inside."

Do i need to install the apk and then move the files, or the other way around?
Can anyone give me a hand, I'm not very good with this.
I apologize for my English

Thanks!!

Comment: i don't think they mean root directory. '*adb push app.apk /data/local/tmp; adb shell pm install /data/local/tmp/app.apk;*'

Comment: I assume "root" is in this case from the perspective of a PC the Android phone is connected to via MTP protocol. Then the root folder would be the sd-card section `/sdcard`. To move a certain folder there would make sense for Android devices prior to version 10. After installing the app it could use the files stored in this folder.